# IoT gabage monitoring system with my own Android application

Tags: sensors, battery

I'm developing a device system in our campus - my aim is to provide three IoT smart garbage containers that will get the fill level (to determine the space of garbage inside and to inform the garbage collector if the garbage is empty, not yet full and full), temperature and humidity from the garbage bin and will send the information to my application that I'm going to develop.

I don't know how I can connect these three IoT devices which are a fair distance from each other. I know it should be wireless though I can't figure out the exact Arduino device to provide connection to my mobile application.

Answer (score 2):

Does your campus have WiFi? If so, go with EPS8266 if its pins are OK for your sensors.
[ESP Pinout](https://cdn.instructables.com/FJC/J4AP/JH8JBTHA/FJCJ4APJH8JBTHA.LARGE.jpg?auto=webp)

You'd want to keep an eye on power consumption; you'd sample your sensors per desired interval and deep-sleep at all other times. Check out available sleep [here](https://www.losant.com/blog/making-the-esp8266-low-powered-with-deep-sleep). It also has en example of how to sample and send a sensor, and sleep afterwards.

On the application end, you could either use a ready service such as Blynk, or go for a custom solution and send the data on your server. Of course, you would then need to write an API and some sort of application to present your data.

Let me also point out that for measuring garbage level, you should calculate the total volume of your bin and subtract the volume of garbage your sensor detects. Having non-uniform trash would give you some trouble, but it's a good technique for an estimation of garbage volume. Also, if using ultrasonic distance sensors, given the fact that you have temperature readings available, you should compensate your measurements; check [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Temperature-Compensated-Ultrasonic-Range-Finder-Wi/) out.

Comment: thank you! :) please guide me for more details. I don't know how to code on ESP8266 and connect it from those 3 devices.

Comment: have a look at the second tutorial in the link I provided [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-deep-sleep-with-arduino-ide/). He is presenting a very similar project.

Comment: thank you @dBm do I need one breadboard for each sensor devices?

Comment: SIR should I use a wifi-module or not?

Comment: sir another one should we used a battery for it and battery case holder? thank you